# embedding (X)HTML5 widget in random non HTML doctype pages

Tags: html, cross-browser, doctype

Will embedding HTML5 JS widgets (using canvas mainly) in random doctype non HTML5 pages work?

I read that serving XHTML5 does not require the HTML5 doctype but I'm not sure if its will actually work cross browsers.

Comment: Did you spend a few minutes and try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, if you want to include any widget in an XHTML5 page it must comply with the general requirements of XML and XHTML.

Given that, here's a test: http://www.alohci.net/application/xhtml+xml/canvas.xhtml

Every browser that supports `application/xhtml+xml` which is necessary for XHTML5, and also supports canvas will do so regardless of the doctype.

This is because the doctype in pages served as `text/html` is only used to determine which of quirks, almost standards, and standards mode the browser is to use. But pages served as `application/xhtml+xml` always select standards mode.

<sub>Example in linked page is taken from [MDN: Basic usage of Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_usage)</sub>